# How to access a folder outside of the document root in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

My Yii document root is `/var/www/html/check/web`

Now I have to access a folder named `uploads` which is located at `/var/www/html/check/download` , i.e outside my document root.

Now how can i access the folder `download` from the root.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like below:

```
echo Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot');
```

This will return the result you want:

```
var/www/html/check
```

If you want to get your application path, you can:

```
echo Yii::getPathOfAlias('application');
```

OR

To get an Absolute webroot url use `Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true)`. Check [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#baseUrl-detail) and [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace).

Or, Use Yii::getAlias('@uploads').

Comment: 'webroot' is set to `/var/www/html/check/web`

Comment: Check with `Yii::getPathOfAlias('application');`